# Mix sound files on android

Tags: java, android, audio, wav

I was trying to make a program that would take a recording from the microphone, and overlay it on an existing wav file. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to save the file as one file and just want to play it together, you can simply create 2 MediaPlayers and play them at the same time.
If you want to actually create a new file, you would need to read about WAV file structure and go from there.

Comment: i was trying on forming a new file

Comment: @IncrediApp creating 2 Mediaplayers does not work, always perform one after the other.